# Graph API me/accounts endpoint returns empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, endpoint

I send request to Graph API using [https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}](https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=%7Buser-access-token%7D). But data returns empty.

If I use [https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={user-access-token}](https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%7Buser-access-token%7D) it returns name and id. But I want to get page token for accounts. And also I already have "businees_management" permission.

Comment: This endpoint also needs the `pages_show_list` permission.

Comment: I already have this permission.

Comment: Then remove the granted permission from your user account, and log in again to grant the permission again. In that process, Facebook should ask you _which_ pages you want to grant access to.

Comment: Actually I tried this but it doesn't work.